# What is the homeworld of the Quozl like?

Tags: quozl

Presumably the the environmental conditions of the [Quozl](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35179.Quozl) home world reflect their physical appearance.

I know that their home world is dangerously overpopulated but what else do we know about it?

Comment: I've edited out the chatter and tried to make the question more pointed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By implication Quozlene (as compared to Earth) has more landmass, is verdant and has a similar atmospheric composition.

> The viewscreen flickered and in place of the Captain was a world. Distant, heavily magnified, and computer-enhanced, but beautiful enough to take one’s breath away. A world not unlike Quozlene itself, rich with bright color and cloud.
>   Politeness had its limits. As soon as the image appeared on the screen, several members of the audience could no longer restrain themselves. Whistles and hums of delight echoed through the chamber despite the frowns of some Seniors.
>   It was far away but at first sight was everything any colonist could hope for. Ample water and judging by the cloud formations, rain. That might mean trees, the soulmates of every Quozl. Not a nightmare desert world. Another Azel, perhaps, or Moszine.

Its gravity is moderately less than 1g.

> Gravity slightly less than that of the Sequencer and Quozlene. A
>   noticeable but not significant difference.

Earth smells *more*.

> Shiraz was an aromatic paradise. There seemed no attempt by either the
>   flora or fauna to disguise their identifying odors, as there was on
>   Quozlene.

Earth's day-night cycle is short than Quozlene's which would suggest that their home planet spins slower than Earth.

> “The day is ending, a shorter one than we are used to. We must leave.”

Their world is an ancient world, tectonically inactive.

> Now they found themselves in country barren to human and Quozl alike,
>   though their guests were impressed by the gray ramparts of the eastern
>   Sierra Nevada. As Runs explained, the records indicated Quozlene was a
>   world of hills and valleys, geologically ancient, too tired for
>   tectonic dramatics. Its mountains were ground down and its canyons
>   filled in. Not so Shiraz.